# Creating Dynamically Accordion Based on Selected Value in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 4 in my application.I am having a select drop down and based on selected drop down value i want to create the dynamic that much accordion with handing 1 ,handing 2...etc.

```
                       <div class="col s2">
                               <div class="select-wrapper drop-select">
                                    <select >
                                    <option value="3">3</option>  
                                      <option value="4">4</option>          
                                      <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                         </div>


     <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Suppose user have selected 3 value from drop down then i should have 3 accordion group.Can any one suggest me how we can do in angular 4.

Comment: Please don't use `angularjs` tag for questions about `angular`

Comment: Research using a loop with `*ngFor`.

Comment: @RickS: I have tried but not able to success.Could u plz create any example for that if possible

Comment: Your sample code shows no events on your dropdown and no ngFor on your accordion.  Show what you have tried and then we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the issue by using ng for loop